# Equation involving 2 variables and Four states of each variable

Tags: logic, systems-of-equations

Variable 1 can assume 4 possible values : ( F, S, In-P, No-Op)

Variable 2 can assume 4 possible values : ( F, S, In-P, No-Op)

Following is the Truth table

1. F + * => F
2. No-Op + * => *
3. S + * => *
4. In-P + * => In-P

`*` => Read this as `any value` of second variable.

I am trying to find a Mathematical function/equation that can solve/represent this.

Note:

1. You can assign any Value to 4 states.
2. Value of '*' is the same on the left and right-hand side of equations.For instance , 2 possibilities for second equation is

   No-Op + F = F

   No-Op + S = S

3.`+` is an operation and not 'Addition'.

We need to find `+` i.e. Operation and Values for the four states which will hold true for all the 4 equations.